# Book on OpenGL _2D_ programming?

Tags: opengl, 2d, gpu, rendering-engine

I need to draw hundreds (maybe thousands!) of images to the screen.  Majority of the work is going to be in 2d.  It'll use some 3d for camera, transforms, rotating scene, but mainly concerned with 2d performance.  Any book on this specific subject?

1) Learn best practices in 2d OpenGL programming

2) Shaders and fancy effects

3) Optimizing 2d rendering operations.

Comment: Usually most things that apply to 3D also apply to 2D. Especially since you are going to still use 3D coordinates to get layering. This question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/239917/getting-started-with-opengl is probably the best list of books for openGL that we have on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you read some books you can improve your skills, like how to do fancy effects, optimizing 2d rendering operations... I think there aren't books teach you how to do only a thing, read and read, study and study is the only way, then you can point on a specific thing with your skills and trying... This is a Programmer !

1. OpenGL Programming Guide: The Official Guide to Learning OpenGL, Version 2.1 By Dave Shreiner, Mason Woo, Jackie Neider, Tom Davis
2. Advanced Graphics Programming Using OpenGL By Tom McReynolds
3. OpenGL Game Programming by Dave Astle and Kevin Hawkins
4. Programming OpenGL ES Game Development by Dave Astle and Dave Durnil
5. Beginning OpenGL Game Programming by Dave Astle and Kevin Hawkins

Answer (score 2):

Focus your energy on learning standard (3D) OpenGL. Using exclusively 2D is just a way of managing the scene (such as orthographic projection with depth testing disabled). You'll still need all the 3D knowledge to achieve any of those fancy effects. For instance, fancy lighting will still require a knowledge of how normals work, and rotating a sprite entails rotating a quad about the Z-axis (despite the scene only working with X and Y). You will use scaling to emulate zooming and whatnot.